# How to create sitemaps with only non-www URLs in MediaWiki website?

Tags: sitemap, mediawiki, no-www

I usually prefer the non-www URL for my website (`http://example.com`, not `http://www.example.com`). While submitting the site to Google [one needs to set a preferred domain](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/44231) by choosing either the `www` or the `non-ww`w version of URL. Then, during submitting the sitemap, [only the sitemap containing the preferred version of URL should be submitted to Google search console](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/oBMSduSWeQ4;context-place=topicsearchin/webmasters/sitemap$20www$20or$20non-www).

I have a website run by [MediaWiki software](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki). It uses a PHP script (named [generateSitemap.php](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:GenerateSitemap.php), it is bundled with the MediaWiki installation package) to create the sitemaps. One can set cron jobs to automate the process of updating sitemap at regular intervals.

The problem is my sitemap are being generated containing the `www` version of the webpages.

How should I instruct the programs to generate sitemaps without `www` in the URLs?

Comment: Does the `$wgServer` value (in `LocalSettings.php`) have the www?

Comment: Maybe you could post-process the sitemap and use `sed` to remove the www.   Add that to the same cron job.

Comment: @unor, Yes, that was the problem. I corrected it and the sitemap is now producing non-www links. Thank you. Should I add an answer to this question?

Comment: @Arnb: Great :) Sure, post an answer and accept it.